# Do While Type Mismatch

Tags: vba, while-loop, type-mismatch

I am getting a type mismatch error on my IF statement. I can't seem to resolve it. Your help is appreciated!

```
Sub practice()

    Dim i As Long
    Dim myrange As Range
    Set myrange = Worksheets("test").Range("A1:O26")
    
    i = 1
    
    Do While i <= 9999
        If Worksheets("test").Range("A1:O26").Offset(0, i - 1).Value = "" Then
            
            Exit Do
        
        End If
        
        Worksheets("test_table").Range("rest_out").Offset((i - 1) * 24, 0) =_ 
        Worksheets("test").Range("A1:O26").Offset(0, i - 1)
        Worksheets("test_table").Range("rest_out").Offset((i - 1) * 24, 0).Font.Bold = True
        
        i = i + 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: You're comparing an array to a string.

Comment: `.Offset` returns a range object.  It is your current range shifted by some number of cells.  You can't take the `.Value` of a range.  Are you trying to compare just one cell?

Comment: You can't compare multiple values directly to a single value, which is what you are currently doing in your If statement. What are you actually trying to check with the If statement?